# How create state machine with notifications and sns topic in same tempale?

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

Consider a code:

serverless.yml

```
service: my-service

frameworkVersion: ">=1.38.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-cf-vars
  - serverless-parameters

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  region: us-east-1

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStateMachine:
      name: my_state_machine
      notifications:
        ABORTED:
          - sns:
              Ref: SnsTopic
        FAILED:
          - sns:
              Ref: SnsTopic
      definition:
        StartAt: "Just Pass"
        States:
          "Just Pass":
            Type: Pass
            End: true
Resources:
  SnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: MySnsTopic
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "^2.5.0",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^2.10.0",
    "serverless-cf-vars": "^0.3.2",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "3.2.7",
    "serverless-aws-nested-stacks": "^0.1.2",
    "serverless-parameters": "0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Failed with error:

```
Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [SnsTopic] in the Resources block of the template
```

So it looks like when state machine is created there is no `SnsTopic` resource. But how to create it before state machine?
`DependsOn` attrobute on state machine lead to same error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is quite trivial (facepalm):

```
resources:
  Resources:
    SnsTopic:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        TopicName: MySnsTopic
```